# Is there a way to change the RevealAnimator color?

Tags: android, animator

I would like to use the `RevealAnimator` effect to show my fragments, by using the following code:

```
ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, ...);
```

It returns a `RevealAnimator` which just animates the revealClip property of the given view.

The question is: is there a way to set a border color and a width to the animated circle?